# Connection to SSH server times out

Tags: ssh

I have ssh configured for my system. It was working perfectly but now I'm able to ssh or sc to other systems but other systems are not able to ssh or scp to my system it shows connection timed out error. Please Help.

Comment: What message do you get when you run `ssh`

Comment: I am able to ssh when I do so it asks me for password and Im able to login but others are not it gives them error connection timed out.

Comment: Firewall? What's the output of `sudo iptables -L -nv`?

Comment: I looked into iptables using iptables -L I have updated the output above I think its got to do something with iptables.

Comment: @Eric: Updated the output for iptables -L -nv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UFW is blocking incoming connections to port 22. Run this to allow it:

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```